# linkstyling css exception? css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink

Howdy,
I love this neat thing found on css-tricks:

```
a:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

Every link gives a little trigger-response.

However, I want *almost* all my links to do that, except the ones inside of `.children`.

Can I create an exception like `:not` (from jQuery) within CSS?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add an additional style rule in CSS, no need for JavaScript, like this:

```
.children a:active {
  position: static;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You *technically* don’t need `top: 0px` in there, as `top` doesn’t have any effect on elements with `position: static`. But this is mere nitpicking.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.children a:active {
  /* whatever */
}
```

assuming your use of ".children" is a class